# Why the getComputedStyle.width/Height giving different values in chrome and edge for display:inline?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have custom element with default value set to 'display' (i.e 'inline'),when I am doing getComputedStyle.Height/Width  in chrome it is returning values in pixel but in the Edge/safari it is returning 'auto'.Is this is a bug in edge? Shouldn't be   computed values always be in pixel?

Comment: Explain? No. Probably a flaw in the official definition of what this is supposed to be, leading to ambiguity. The answer to your unasked question though, is `offsetHeight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discuss the issue with senior MSFT developers. they informed me that MS Edge browser engine will ignore the style values that you had specifically set for the elements when you use '**display: inline;**' and it assigns default values like **auto**. So because of this reason, MS Edge returns the **auto** value instead of number of pixels. To get the number of pixels you can remove the 'display: inline;'.

This is by design and it cannot be consider as a bug.

Thanks for your understanding.